# Artifactory or Nexus deploy Jar and Pom

Tags: maven, curl, nexus, artifactory, sonatype

I've got a compiled Jar file and a Pom file. Now I want to deploy both of these to Artifactory or Nexus (I've got both).

I want to do it with either mvn:deploy or curl (REST API)

could someone tell me how I do this?

Comment: See http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management and https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21283268-Configure-Maven-to-Deploy-to-Nexus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answers are about Artifactory, of course.

For using `mvn deploy` you need to configure your pom file to include `distributionManagement` tag. Y[ou can copy-paste the whole tag from Artifactory UI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Maven#WorkingwithMaven-DeployingArtifactsThroughArtifactory) (click on the repository you want to deploy to, on the right side you'll see the `distributionMnagement` tag for copying).

With REST API you can just issue two [PUT requests](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact) (one for pom, other for jar). Start with the pom.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a jar file already as well as a pom, you would want to use the deploy-file goal of the Maven deploy plugin. mvn deploy will build the project but that wont work if you already got the jar and pom file and no source code.

Of course you can also [upload the files via the web user interface of Nexus](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) or use [the REST api.](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-plugins.html) You can find some REST api examples [with curl on github](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-introduction-presentation/tree/master/labs/rest-api-scripting).